# Write Non-BMP Code Points to Console

Tags: c, windows, winapi

The Windows console API provides the [`WriteConsoleOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms687404(v=vs.85).aspx) function, which allows you to write characters to arbitrary locations on the console.  This function takes an array of [`CHAR_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682013(v=vs.85).aspx) structures as an argument, specifying the:

1. Characters (i.e. code points) to write
2. Attributes thereof

However the `CHAR_INFO` structure allows code points to be specified only as either `WCHAR` or `CHAR`.  `CHAR` supports only ANSI characters, and `WCHAR` supports only code points in the range U+0000 to U+FFFF (i.e. [the BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)).

Is there any way to use the console API to write out code points in the range U+10000 to U+10FFFF?  I.e. to write code points outside of the BMP?

Comment: Do you have any constant-width fonts installed on your machine that have characters outside of the BMP?

Comment: [Surrogates and Supplementary Characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374069(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @ooga: Nothing on that page talks about the console subsystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the Windows console API is limited to UCS2 and so cannot output non-BMP characters.